# Opening Existing angular 8 application in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

Is there any way to import an existing Angular application into Visual studio 2017?
I know how to open the project solution using VS Code. But I am trying to do so in Visual Studio.

I found that I can create a new .NET Core web application and copy my Angular app files to the Client App directory.

Is there another way to open directly the Angular project without creating a .NET Core application?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can create a simple blank solution and add your clientapp directory like :

[image: new solution illustration]